# table view bottom constraint won't animate/change

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to animate the table view to move up when the keyboard appears (I don't want to use content inset for this because I have an additional view). I have the following code:

```
view.addSubview(tableView)
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let tableViewBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
    item: tableView,
    attribute: .bottom,
    relatedBy: .equal,
    toItem: view,
    attribute: .bottom,
    multiplier: 1.0,
    constant: 0.0
)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
])

view.addConstraint(tableViewBottomConstraint)
self.tableViewBottomConstraint = tableViewBottomConstraint

view.addSubview(messageTextView)
messageTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    messageTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    messageTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
    messageTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
])
```

When I receive a keyboard notification I do the following:

```
tableViewBottomConstraint?.constant = info.endFrame.height

UIView.animate(
    withDuration: info.animationDuration,
    delay: 0.0,
    options: info.animationOptions,
    animations: {
        self?.view?.layoutIfNeeded()
    },
    completion: nil
```

However nothing happens. The table view does not move at all. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need

```
tableViewBottomConstraint?.constant = -1 * info.endFrame.height
```

The reason is instead of cutting from the constant value you are adding to it so the table increases in height